# Magento Add to cart button with predefined quantity

Tags: magento

How to Add quantity for this add to cart button code:

```
onclick="setLocation('
  <?php 
     echo (string)Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl(Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($prod->getId()));
  ?>
')"
```

Comment: Can you share with us the getAddUrl function you're calling?

Comment: <?php
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
->getCollection()
->joinField('category_id', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id', 'product_id = entity_id', null, 'left')
->addAttributeToSelect('*')->setPageSize(1)
->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => $categoryIds));
foreach($products as $prod) {
 ?>            
<button type="button" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo (string)Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl(Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($prod->getId()));?>')">
</button>
         <?php 
}
 ?>
I just need to pass the quantity.How do I achieve this?

Comment: When I look at the source code it's like this:

<button class="submit" onclick="setLocation('siteurl/index.php/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovL2N3Y3dwLmluL2hhdGNoYm94L2luZGV4LnBocA,,/product/1/form_key/rYarAayY2q49gMyW/')" id="addcart1" type="button">
<span>ADD To Cart</span><img src="siteurl/skin/frontend/rwd/default/images/add-to-cart.png">
</button>

Comment: if there's a way to pass the qty param to the url

<button class="submit" onclick="setLocation('siteurl/index.php/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovL2N3Y3dwLmluL2hhdGNoYm94L2luZGV4LnBocA,,/product/1/qty/1/form_key/rYarAayY2q49gMyW/')" id="addcart1" type="button">
<span>ADD To Cart</span><img src="siteurl/skin/frontend/rwd/default/images/add-to-cart.png">
</button>

after product/1 the qty/1..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Mage_Checkout_Helper_Cart getAddUrl` suggests that you can pass through the product as the first parameter, and an `$additional` array too.  This additional array can include `qty` as a key, with a value.

So, you can call:

```
$additional = array("qty"=> 3);
echo (string)Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl(Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($prod->getId()), $additional);
```

Comment: Great! If it's everything you need, please accept this as the answer :)